# Why did a git pull origin master not work, but a git pull did?

Tags: git, branch, git-pull

So I ran into a peculiar problem this morning, and I was wondering if the community could help me figure it out.  So I've been doing `git pull origin master` when I want to fetch and merge the projects changes from the remote master copy and bring them to my local master.

I've been running into some merging issues lately though, so I did an experiment - 
I did a `git pull origin master` like always, and got the message that said *"Already up-to-date."*

Then I did a normal `git pull` and then saw all of my coworkers changes rolling in and merging with my local master branch.

Why did a git pull origin master not work, but a git pull did?

I wonder how many changes I haven't been seeing because of this quirk I discovered.  I've done some research to find out what the differences are but I still haven't found a reason why my repo wasn't being updated properly with a git pull origin master, when I've seen changes being fetched and merged into my branch with that method before.

Thoughts?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like your local branch isn't tracking what you think it is. Try issuing `git remote show origin` and check the "Local branch configured for 'git pull':" section. `git pull` without specification will default from the "remote" and "merge" configuration of the current branch, per the man page:

> Default values for  and  are read from the "remote" and "merge" configuration for the current branch as set by git-branch(1) --track.

I'd bet you have a different branch configured for tracking than `origin/master`. It's also possible you're pulling from a different remote. To verify these possibilities, try:

```
git config branch.master.remote ;# shows you the tracked remote
git config branch.master.merge ;# shows you the tracked upstream branch
```

These assume your local branch is called `master`.

Comment: Interesting. I did a `git remote show origin` like you suggested and the "local branch configured for git pull" section says `master merges with remote master` and the "configured for git push" section just below that says `master pushes to master (up to date)`.  Is there a difference here between 'remote master' and 'master' with these configuration settings? Thanks again.

Comment: That sounds correct, but there are still a few possible configurations that could generate what you noticed. Did you try the two `git config` commands? Mind adding the output from them to your question? It'll help responders debug.

Answer (score -3):

By the sounds of things you are pulling down other branches. Either the other devs are working on another branch or you are in a detached state and no longer on a branch / their branch.

If you run `git branch --all` it will show you all of the branches on your project.

To switch back to master just run: `git checkout master`

Hope this helps